# Django static files link

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles, static-files

thanks for looking into this, cause it's getting on my nerves now:)

I can't get a style.css (or any static file to get oared at all!) and I have googled around and none of the solutions worked so far.

my urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
 from django.conf import settings

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', 'ports.views.home', name='home'),
 )
 urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

 if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
)
```

my base.html where i load the statics:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
...
```

my settings.py references the static directory:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong (or in fact why it has to be so awkward to server these statics). any help in lakers terms would be appreciated!

Thanks,
blargie-bla

Comment: Is this on a real server or are you just running `./manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score 2):

On your server, you probably need to try this

```
python manage.py collectstatic -l
```

The `-l` makes a symbolic link instead of copying. This prevents two copies of the same file and save some space, but also means if you rename the original file, you'll have to reestablish the link.

More info about the collectstatic command [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

Don't forget to set [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root) as well.

Just for reference here is my `settings.py` for that part:

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static').replace('\\', '/')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This applies for Django 1.4+, where the `settings.py` is under (for example) `mysite/mysite/` and it's not on the same level as the `static` folder.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was adding the css outside block content. Moving it inside the block content solved the issue.

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">-->
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

     --some code--

{% endblock content%
```

Comment: You are extended a base template and then placing content outside of a block.
You might want to create a block in base.html called styles and then in extending templates you can insert/include your stylesheet:

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block style %}
<link ...>
{ endblock %}
{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```